# How do I merge all data frames in the global environment?

Tags: r, merge

I have dozens of data frames in the global environment. I want to merge all of them without typing the names of all of them.

How do I do this?

Comment: `DF_list = ls()` ; `merged_DF = Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by= common_variable), DF_list )` , you can use `ls()` to list all datasets and specify common variable among these datasets

Comment: merge horizontally (à la `merge()`) or vertically (à la `rbind()`)?  Do you have any other objects in your global environment?  The basic ingredients are `ls()` + `get()` + (`rbind()` or `merge()`) + (`do.call()` or `Reduce`) ...

Comment: @BenBolker merge horizontally

Comment: sounds like the problem started when you created dozens of data frames in your global environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @Osssan's comments, and assuming that you want to merge *everything* in your global workspace,

Get the names of the objects and then retrieve the objects themselves into a list:

```
DF_obj <- lapply(ls(), get)
```

If you want to merge on all common variables (e.g. if all variable names are unique except the one(s) you want to merge on), then just

```
Reduce(merge, DF_obj)
```

should work.

Unfortunately (unlike `lapply()` etc.) `Reduce` doesn't have a `...` argument for passing additional named arguments to a function, so `Reduce(merge, DF_obj, by=common_variable)` doesn't work; as @Osssan points out you need something like

```
mergefun <- function(x, y) merge(x, y, by= "common_variable")
merged_DF <- Reduce(mergefun, DF_obj )
```

As other commenters point out, if you just kept the data frames in a list in the first place, you could dispense with the `ls()`/`get()` step, which is typically clunky/fragile (what if you want to pass the objects back from a function?  what if you only want to merge some of the objects in the workspace? ...)

Comment: Hm, I do have a list of all data frames' names.

Comment: I also ran this code: `dfObj <- lapply(ls(), get),
mergeFunc <- function(x,y) merge(x, y, by=rank),
mergedDF <- Reduce(mergeFunc, dfObj)`, where the commas are newlines, but I got this error: `Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'`

Comment: your merge variable name needs to be in quotes: `by="rank"`