# map_dfr to bind_rows all the data frames in the global environment

Tags: r, data-binding, concatenation, purrr

I was hoping for a tidyverse friendly update to [a 2016 question about merging all data-frames in the global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725013/how-do-i-merge-all-data-frames-in-the-global-environment).

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

Alberta <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Alberta")%>% 
  html_node('body #content #bodyContent #mw-content-text .mw-parser-output table') %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) 

`British Columbia` <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_British_Columbia")%>% 
  html_node('body #content #bodyContent #mw-content-text .mw-parser-output table') %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) 
`British Columbia`$Coordinates  %<>%  str_remove(., pattern="^.*\\}")

Manitoba <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Manitoba")%>% 
  html_node('body #content #bodyContent #mw-content-text .mw-parser-output table') %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
Manitoba$Coordinates  %<>%  str_remove(., pattern="^.*\\}")
```

I have more places so obviously this is why I want to `purrr`. My work-around was to do `` sprintf('`%s`', ls()) %>% cat(sep = ",") `` and then copy-paste that into
`` Airports <- bind_rows(`Alberta`,`British Columbia`,`Manitoba`, .id="Province") `` since I couldn't get `bind_rows` to accept the `sprintf` function as an argument, nor could I get it to save as an object (`NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

If the objects created in the current session are all those datasets, use `mget` on the object names in the `ls` to return a `list` of data.frames and return a single dataset with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mget(ls()), .id = 'Province')
```

---

If we want to read this in a loop without creating any objects in the global env

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
v1 <- c("Alberta", "British_Columbia", "Manitoba")
links <- glue::glue("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_{v1}")

out <- map_dfr(links, ~ read_html(.x) %>%
   html_node('body #content #bodyContent #mw-content-text .mw-parser-output table') %>% 
   html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(Coordinates = str_remove(Coordinates, pattern = "^.*\\}")),
            .id = "Province")
```

-output

```
dim(out)
#[1] 725   7
head(out)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Province Community        `Airport name`                  ICAO  `TC LID` IATA  Coordinates                                                                 
  <chr>    <chr>            <chr>                           <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>                                                                       
1 1        Airdrie          Airdrie Aerodrome               ""    "CEF4"   ""    51°15′50″N 113°56′04″W / 51.26389°N 113.93444°W / 51.26389; -113.93444 (Air…
2 1        Alhambra         Alhambra/Ahlstrom Aerodrome     ""    "CAM4"   ""    52°20′45″N 114°40′02″W / 52.34583°N 114.66722°W / 52.34583; -114.66722 (Alh…
3 1        Athabasca        Athabasca Airport               "CYW… ""       ""    54°44′35″N 113°12′19″W / 54.74306°N 113.20528°W / 54.74306; -113.20528 (Ath…
4 1        Athabasca oil s… Anzac (Long Lake) Heliport      ""    "CNZ2"   ""    56°25′27″N 110°57′52″W / 56.42417°N 110.96444°W / 56.42417; -110.96444 (Anz…
5 1        Banff            Banff Airport                   "CYB… ""       ""    51°12′30″N 115°32′25″W / 51.20833°N 115.54028°W / 51.20833; -115.54028 (Ban…
6 1        Banff            Banff Mineral Springs (Hospita… ""    "CBM7"   ""    51°10′47″N 115°34′34″W / 51.17972°N 115.57611°W / 51.17972; -115.57611 (Ban…
```

Comment: to the rescue in record time as usual! Any idea about purrr? I've used an assign( envir=.GlobalEnv) on a function that maps through read_xlsx in the past 
```
xlxs_names %>%  purrr::map(function(file_name){ # iterate through each file name
    assign(x = str_remove(file_name, ".xlsx"), # Remove file extension
           value = read_xlsx(paste0(file_path, file_name)),
           envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
```